# Is there a way to simplify two functions being convoluted with the same function?

Tags: calculus, convolution

Is there a way to simplify two functions being convoluted with the same function, i.e. can I simplify:

\begin{align}
\left[ f(t) * w(t) \right] \left[ g(t) * w(t) \right] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) w(t - \tau) d\tau \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(\tau) w(t - \tau) d\tau
\end{align}

I could solve the two integrals seperately, but I'm looking for a more elegant approach.

Comment: Have you considered using direct and/or inverse Fourier transform ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, yes but I don't think this helps as the multiplication gets transformed in a convolution and vice versa. We'd end up with:

\begin{equation}
F(\omega) W(\omega) * G(\omega) W(\omega)
\end{equation}

Comment: Indeed, I don't think that this product can be transformed in something else...